# How to save files to the location where the original file is in using vba?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am writing a simple macro to do the followings:
1. remove all the formats
2. unhide all the hidden columns
3. keep the four specified tabs: "Forms", "Fields", "DataDictionaries" and "DataDictionaryEntries"
4. save the file (with those four tabs) under the location where the original file is in.

Here is my code:

```
Sub removeformat()

Dim sheetlist As Variant
Dim sheet As Variant
sheetlist = Array("Forms", "Fields", "DataDictionaries", "DataDictionaryEntries")

For Each sheet In sheetlist
    Sheets(sheet).Activate
    Sheets(sheet).Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearFormats
    Sheets(sheet).Cells(1, 1).Select
    Sheets(sheet).Columns("A:IV").Hidden = False

Next sheet

Sheets(Array("Forms", "Fields", "DataDictionaries", "DataDictionaryEntries")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="File to Upload", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

The problem is the fourth step. It won't save to the original file location, it is saved to the excel default location instead. Could you guys help me with this problem please? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save in the same location as ActiveWorkbook then that is given by ActiveWorkBook.Path

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "File to Upload", _
                      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Should I just change SaveAs to Path then?

Comment: Hi Tim Williams, I tried your code, however, it showed me: Run-time error: MS Excel cannot access the file.. Did I do this wrong?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "File to Upload", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close

Comment: Where are you wanting to save the file - what exactly is the "original file location" ?